# Firefox unable to drag out inline base64 images

Tags: firefox, images

In Firefox, if I drag out an image, it will open a new tab displaying only the image.

And sometimes ago, it can drag out inline base64 images. But now, I can't do it.

You can try drag the images at 
https://cdn.rawgit.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/master/output_HTML/marham.html

[image]

Most of it can't open a new tab.

I'm not sure what's wrong with this, because not long ago I was able to do this.

UPDATE:

Bug reports:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729587
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923832

Comment: Where do you drop when you drag an image?  I drop on the + sign on the tabs and it opens the image in a new tab

Comment: Just [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). In the meantime you can workaround by using right click -> View image, with Ctrl being held down.

Comment: @TomYan Find several links and posted in the question. But unluckily, they are not resolved. (However, I do remember I can do this several weeks ago.)